# Ballerina : Idle timeout triggered before initiating inbound response

Tags: http, ballerina

I am executing Task appointment in a ballerina project which runs every 10 minutes. It works fine for roughly an hour but when the execution time reaches 2 hours it gives me an error. Following is the error log.

```
2018-10-04 12:00:00,002 INFO - Scanning the Github repository
2018-10-04 12:01:00,008 ERROR - Idle timeout triggered before initiating inbound response : {message:"Idle timeout triggered before initiating inbound response", cause:null, statusCode:0}
```

It seems the idle time is 1 minute from the error log.

Here is the program code.

```
public function main(string... args) {

        log:printInfo("------ Scheduling Appointments --------------");   

        (function() returns error?) onTriggerFunction = gitHubTaskExecute;
        (function(error)) onErrorFunction = gitGubTaskError;

        gitGubTask = new task:Appointment(onTriggerFunction, 
                                            onErrorFunction, 
                                            "0 30 1 * * ?");

        gitGubTask.schedule();
    }
}

@Description { value:"Execute the Github repository scanning task"}
function gitHubTaskExecute() returns (error?) {
    log:printInfo("Scanning the Github repository : " + repository);
    executedTaskCount = executedTaskCount + 1;
    if (executedTaskCount == 100) {
        log:printInfo("Stopping Appointment#1 cleanup task since it
                       has run 100 times");

        gitGubTask.cancel();
    }
    return cleanup();
}

@Description { value:"Execute the task cleanup"}
function cleanup() returns (error?) {
    //Call function here

    return ();
}
```

Any idea what is triggering this error? I want to implement a task which should be executed daily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that IdleTimeout triggers when the connection is idle for more than the specified period. Then the server/client would close the connection with an appropriate response. You can set it to `>= 0` if you would like to disable it.

Sample client endpoint:

```
endpoint http:Client clientEndpoint {
    url: "http://localhost:9090",
    timeoutMillis: 300000
};
```

There is a configuration called `timeoutInMillis` in the http client and server endpoints.  You can increase this value if it is the requirement.